# Want to Display User Image after successful login in navbar

Tags: angular, frontend

I purchased an angular theme name is "EMBRYO" in it i want to display a user image after a successful login 
here is my home.component.ts code...:

```
    export class HeaderOneComponent implements OnInit , OnDestroy 
     {
       ngOnDestroy(): void {
       throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
     }
        isLogin : boolean = false;
        toggleActive     : boolean = false;
        cartProducts     : any;
        popupResponse    : any;
        wishlistProducts : any;
        httpClient: any;

      constructor(public embryoService: EmbryoService, private 
        user: UserdataService) {}

          ngOnInit() {
        let data = localStorage.getItem('isLogin');
        console.log(data);   
        if(data === 'true'){
        console.log('working');
        this.isLogin = true;
       }
     {
     this.user.getUserdata()
        .subscribe(data => {
           console.log(data)
        });
      }

     this.user.postUserdata()
        .subscribe(data => {
           console.log("POST Request is successful", data);
        }, error  => {
           console.log("Error", error);
        });

     console.log('home')
```

}

And this is my signin component ts file code.

export class CommonSignInComponent implements OnInit {

```
  @ViewChild('UserLoginForm') UserLoginForm: NgForm;
    user = {
    email:'',
    password:''
}

    constructor(
    private router: Router,
) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    console.log('login')
}
    loginForm() {
    localStorage.setItem('isLogin' , 'true' )
    const data = this.UserLoginForm.value;
    console.log(data);
    this.user.email = data.email;
    this.user.password = data.password;
    console.log(this.user);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
    }

  }
```

Please let me know how i manage all the things just want to show user profile into my navvbar.

Here is the Home Component HTML file...

```
            <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="header-v2">
  <mat-toolbar-row class="header-v2-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div fxLayout="row wrap">
        <div class="logo-site" fxFlex.xs="50" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.md="35" fxFlex.lg="25%" fxFlex.xl="25%">
         <embryo-AppLogo></embryo-AppLogo>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex.sm="60" fxHide.xs="true" fxHide.sm="true" fxFlex.md="40" fxFlex.sm.hdie fxFlex.lg="60%" fxFlex.xl="60%" class="align-center">

           <div class="search-v2">
              <form action="">
                 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a keyword to search">
              </form>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex.xs="50" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.md="25" fxFlex.lg="15%" fxFlex.xl="15%">
      <span fxFlex></span>
          <div class="list-flex user-tool">
              <a *ngIf="!isLogin" mat-button [routerLink]="['/session/signup']">Register</a>
              <a *ngIf="!isLogin" mat-button [routerLink]="['/session/signin']">Login</a>
            <!-- <embryo-HeaderCart [currency]="embryoService?.currency" [cartProducts]="embryoService?.localStorageCartProducts" [count]="embryoService?.navbarCartCount" (removeProductData)="openConfirmationPopup($event)"></embryo-HeaderCart>

            <embryo-WishList [currency]="embryoService?.currency" [wishListProducts]="embryoService?.localStorageWishlist" [count]="embryoService?.navbarWishlistProdCount" (removeWishListData)="openWishlistConfirmationPopup($event)" (addAllWishlistToCart)="addAllWishlistToCart($event)" (addToCart)="addToCart($event)"></embryo-WishList> -->
            <embryo-HeaderUserProfileDropdown *ngIf="isLogin"></embryo-HeaderUserProfileDropdown>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
  <mat-toolbar-row class="header-v2-bottom main-menu-wrap">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header-v2-bottom-inner">
        <embryo-Menu></embryo-Menu>

      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
  <mat-toolbar-row class="responsive-bar relative">
        <div class="container">
          <div fxLayoutAlign="space-between">

            <button class="responsive-toggle" mat-icon-button 
    (click)="toggleSidebar()">
              <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
            </button>
            <div>
                <div class="search-box-bar">
                  <button type="button" mat-mini-fab 
     (click)="toggleSearch()">
                    <i class="material-icons notranslate">
                      search
                    </i>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="search-form">
                  <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search and hit 
      enter">
                    <button type="button" mat-fab class="close-btn" 
      (click)="toggleSearch()">
                      <i class="material-icons">
                        close
                      </i>
                    </button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-toolbar-row>
     </mat-toolbar>
    <embryo-FixedHeader></embryo-FixedHeader>
```